# Global Hooks (non-active program)

Tags: c#, hook, global, hotkeys

I am creating a program that allows you to paste text but it will look like you are typing it as it pastes, Paste Typer.

I am wanting to use `Ctrl + b` to set off the pasting, but I am having issues with hotkeys.

I think what I need is to use a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook and include that user32 file but I usually get errors when I add it and the namespace.

I have come closest with this: http://thedarkjoker94.cer33.com/?p=111 - but it doesn't seem to work with `Ctrl`, `alt` and other modifiers, even when I used `KeyData`.

I need a way to make a hotkey that will work even when the program is not the active window. This is a windows forms application in Microsoft Visual C# 2010.

There a rea lot of StackOverlow topics but they are dated and are not complete enough for me to get something running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about the [HookManager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx)?

I use it successfully like this:

```
HookManager.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(HookManager_KeyDown);
```

and

```
void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.LWin)) // Is the Left-Windows Key down and ...
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.O: 
                // ...
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            case Keys.H: 
                // ...
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
        }
}
```

I created the Keyboard class here is the code:

```
// Used: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Win32.Devices
{
    public class Keyboard
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern ushort GetAsyncKeyState(Keys vKey);

        public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
        {
            return 0 != (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was talking about that code project article. So what do i have to include to get that? Do i just use the code and class you gave there? I also stumbled upon what appears to be a simple tutorial on this (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ashsimplehotkeys.aspx) but I am still unable to get it to work. I just get a bunch of errors after adding the code

Comment: Add a link to the GlobalHook\Gma.UserActivityMonitor\bin\Debug\Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll and then reference the HookManager class as I did in the code above.  Its possible it was made for .Net 3.5 and before and it may not compile, but the dll that comes with it should work.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I add a link to the file? Do i [DllImport("GlobalHook\Gma.UserActivityMonitor\bin\Debug\Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll")]? And do i have to download anything?

Comment: He's made a new version: http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/  You have to download the dll/source files to use them.  If you have Visual studio, add a **reference** to the file.  Otherwise, you'll have to put another question to StackOverflow 'how do I link a dll without visual studio'

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I am still trying to figure out how to use it. I have the dll as a reference and I added it as a item in my toolbox and i put the MouseKeyEventProvider on and enabled it but i am unsure on how hook something or monitor it.

Comment: I removed the link to the new source on codeplex.  That code doesn't have the HookManager.  You should download the version 2 source files from codeproject here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx  Then link the Gma.UserActiviyMonitor.dll like I mentioned above.  If you don't know how to use events, then you should read up on C# events.  Because my code above shows everything you need to monitor the keyboard event.

Comment: Sorry chuck, I am just not seeing Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll anywhere in the downloads (in both versions and source and demo)

Comment: Open it as a new project/solution and compile it.  Then link it in.